Ubuntu 24.04 keeps changing the screen brightness without me doing anything. How do I stop it?
I just installed ubuntu 24.04 and my laptop is a thinkpad yoga first generation.
The screen brightness keeps going up and down.
I will set it to the brightest, and every other second, I will see it dim, 4 or 5 times, then brighten 4 or 5 times, and it just keeps going.
Is there any way I can just disabled the ability for the screen brightness to go up or down one way or the other?
Thanks.

Does this machine have any kind of light sensor that adjusts to the room light?

@David Its a thinkpad x1 yoga first generation. Its a good question because I noticed it was adjusting as there was sunlight peering at the screen over my shoulder. I've just never heard of or seen such a feature in thinkpads.

(disclaimer: I don't know if 24.04 supports these---I'm running 22.04 and having the same problem as you, and neither of these options work for me.)
At least on devices that support the auto brightness feature, you can run this command to turn it off:
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power ambient-enabled false

To turn it back on:
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power ambient-enabled true

Note that from my experience, those commands don't work on 22.04.
Alternatively, there may be a setting that can disable this behavior. Try settings --> power --> "Automatic Screen Brightness" (under Power Saving Options). If that option is there, it will disable the automatic brightness feature.
